# Configure aptana 2.0.1 with zend framework 1.10.3 enable tooltip

Tags: zend-framework, aptana, configure

I see in video tutorial there is or plugin or spesial setting for aptana studio.When whrite in studio pop up variaty functions and objects with description particularly with zend framework.

How to set up a studio ?or what plugin use for this?

Answer (score 1):

Going to project properties --> PHP include path
In libraries tab, click Add Library
In new dialogue (User libraries) press Config
In filtered preferences dialogue that comes up press new
Give it a name and press OK
With new library name selected, press Add external folder and navigate to ZF library folder (overall path should be like /usr/local/ZendFrameworkCli/library)
Click OK for PHP Libraries
New library should now be in list of User libraries dialogue. Put a checkbox next to library you just created

find in http://alex-tech-adventures.com/faq/1-zend-framework-faq/3-how-to-get-aptana-or-another-php-ide-to-display-zf-inteli-tips.html

Answer (score 1):

This director '/usr/local/ZendFrameworkCli/library' does not exist.